# Is there a standard directory in Linux where my driver files are stored?

Tags: drivers

I need to find my drivers for the sound card and graphic card, do you know how to find their paths and if they are stored logically in one directory?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For Redhat derivatives, drivers are found in

```
/lib/modules/$Kernel_version/kernel/drivers/
```

You can see the status of the drivers in the kernel by using `lsmod`.

You can find info on a module by using `modinfo` which will show you the location.

For example

```
modinfo cryptd  
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64/kernel/crypto/cryptd.ko
description:    Software async crypto daemon
license:        GPL
srcversion:     8AB98AD1F94057A296739AB
depends:        
vermagic:       2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions
```

Comment: Most distros are using the kmod package for `modprobe` and other `mod*` tools, the root dir is likely a configuration parameter of tha package.

Comment: Ubuntu and derivatives is the same location:  /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/